# Are all md5 hashes the same?

Tags: php, security, bash, md5

If I create an md5 hash for a string on one cpmputer using a bash script, will that same string create the same md5 hash if I were to cerate an md5 hash via a php script on another computer?  I'm trying to write a script on one computer and port it to another.  That script will create an md5 hash for a user password.  Then, a seperate web page will ask for a username and password.  As I do not want to store the raw password I'd like to store the hash, have the php script compute the hash for the password that the user enters, and grant access if they match up.  Should this theoretically work, or are there issues that I need to consider?

Comment: Yes, it should. Nay, it *will*.

Comment: salt your hashes...And MD5 is broken, BTW...

Comment: Asking if `md5` will produce the same answer for the same input is like asking if `2 + 2` will always give `4`.

Comment: Unless you mess with the encodings on your inserts/updates, both md5's should be identical.

Comment: [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) has emerged as a better option for password hashing since `md5` was broken ... you should use that or one of the *many* other secure hashing algorithms, but probably not `md5`

Comment: If @Kolink's comment was an answer then that would have been the top answer! :P

Comment: @Jaypal: I was going to make it an answer, but I decided it was too rude :p

Comment: If you are going for something safe (and if it is available) go for something like PBKDF2. MD5 is pretty broken, but it's still relatively safe (for now) for key derivation, although I certainly would recommend SHA-256 over MD5 or SHA-1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, MD5 checksums are platform agnostic and will produce the same value every time on the same file/string/whatever.

However, you may want to reconsider your scheme.  At least salt your hashes.  There is tons of advice for username/password storage schemes on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, provided you hash the *same sequence of bytes* on each platform.  Consider this, for example:

```
$ echo 'P4$$w0rd' | md5
9bb60af76b036e37a6d2626868c8c101
$ printf 'P4$$w0rd' | md5
640e5a3b9f9e4d667456c4e68194d6a2
```

Why are the hashes different?  Because `echo` put a newline (ascii LF character) at the end of the string, while `printf` didn't.  You need to make sure that all platforms are encoding the password the same way (i.e. ISO-8859-1 vs. UTF-8 vs. UTF-16 vs. UTF-8 with BOM...), and if anything's added (like the newline) it should be consistent (e.g. Windows tends to use CRLF at the end of lines, instead of just LF...).

Also, as @Mitch Wheat mentioned, for password storage you really should salt the hash (i.e. hash some random data together with the password, then store the random data *and* the hash).  Something stronger than MD5 would be good as well, but that's not nearly as important.  Here's a completely quick-and-dirty implementation:

```
# generate the hash:
read -s -p "Enter a password:" password
echo
salt="$RANDOM"  # Really should use something more random here...
hashedpw="$salt,$(printf "%s|%s" "$salt" "$password" | md5)"

echo "The salted hash is $hashedpw"

# check the hash:
read -s -p "Try to reenter the password:" testpassword
echo
salt="${hashedpw%%,*}"
hashonly="${hashedpw#*,}"
if [ "$hashonly" = "$(printf "%s|%s" "$salt" "$testpassword" | md5)" ]; then
    echo "That was the same password"
else
    echo "That was not the same password"
fi
```

EDIT: here's a better way of generating a random salt, although it's probably not as portable:

```
salt="$(dd if=/dev/random bs=16 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -x | sed 's/^[0-9]*//' | tr -d $' \t\n')"
```

If you want even more randomness, just increase the `bs=16` parameter; that controls the number of bytes of random data that's used.

Comment: What's wrong with `salt=$(tr -d -c 0-9a-f < /dev/random | head -c 32)`? Should be pretty portable and sufficiently random. Efficiency does, I'll admit, suffer a bit.

Comment: @Sorpigal: that won't work on platforms with locale-aware versions of `tr` that expect valid UTF-8 input by default.  `salt=$(LC_ALL=ISO8859-1 tr -d ...` seems to fix this for me, at least on OS X...  Also, since this consumes a lot of extra input, using /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random might be better (actually, it might be better anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in theory that should work. MD5 is a hashing algorithm, so as long as it's using MD5 for both ends, it should work no problem.

There are other, more secure hashing algorithms you might want to consider, like SHA for example. And, as the comments above suggest, you should always salt your hashes to add an extra layer of security...